# You seem to not be depending on "@angular/core" and/or "rxjs". This is an error

Tags: angular

When i run the `ng serve -o` command in my angular project I get the following error:
You seem to not be depending on *@angular/core* and/or *rxjs*. This is an error.

Here are my versions:

- node -v --> 10.6.0
- npm -v --> 6.2.0

Comment: please more information

Answer (score 3):

For those who are still looking for the answer, first check your folder **node_module/@angular** and some of important folders

[image]

If these folders are not there, run command **`npm install`** and then run command **`npm serve`**, it should solve your problem. I ran into same problem because of migrations from Angular 4 to Angular 6 and that's how I fixed it.

Some other suggests the command `npm link` run after `npm install` but I don't think it would need it.

Answer (score 2):

It might be an empty node_modules folder.
Try this:

```
D:\My_Project>npm link
D:\My_Project>ng serve
```

Comment: When I run npm link I get: npm ERR! Invalid version: "^6.083"

Comment: Is your node_modules folder empty?

Comment: No it is not empty. Could it have to do with my angular and node versions?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like YOU'RE not launching the command (`ng serve -o`) in the RIGHT FOLDER ...

check if is there the `package.json` file with a

```
dir (on Windows)
ls (on linux)
```

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

run this command in the angular folder like
`npm install`

after that run command
`ng serve`